# Javascript replace() function and regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, latex

sorry for that ambiguous title.

I am currently coding something in Javascript and I am facing a problem :

I have LaTeX strings that I want to edit in order to keep all its identifiers, but not the syntax of LaTeX.

For instance, if I have "\frac{a}{b}", the regexp I'm going to use will only detect 'a' and 'b'.

However, it's a little bit more complicated than that : I have a list of patterns that I want to delete from my LaTeX string

```
var patternsToDelete = ['\\\\frac', '\\\\partial','\{','\}']
```

And here is the code that I have to replace those patterns by a whitespace :

```
for (ptd in patternsToDelete){
      var re = new RegExp(patternsToDelete[ptd], 'g');
      latex = latex.replace(re,' ');
    }
```

The thing is that I want to delete all the '{' and the '}', but I still want to keep a specific pattern in my string : "textbf{*any identifier*}". 
The problem is that if I have '{' in patternsToDelete, it will also delete the ones of "textbf{...}", but if I don't have '{' in patternsToDelete, the rest of my code won't work either.

My question is : how can I remove every '{' and '}' in my string **except** the ones in my specific pattern (textbf{...})

Thank you very much !

Comment: You are probably looking for a negative lookbehind, which is not supported in JavaScript.

Comment: Can you do something like if(latex.match(re)) { //do something}else{//replace}

Comment: Oh, I see ... in that case what I'd need would be a regexp that matches every identifier in a LaTeX equation, have you ever heard of such a regexp?